# Can constants be complex for integral table?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-numbers

There is a fairly well know definite integral, that appears on the tables:

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-(ax^2 + bx+c)}~dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{(b^2-4ac)/4a}$$

Will this be correct if $a$, $b$, or $c$ are complex? Or, putting it another way:

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-(iax^2 + ibx)}~dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{ia}}e^{ib^2/4a}$$

Is this true?

Comment: If it did work, I think we should expect $(ib)^2 = -b^2$, not $ib^2$, and the reciprocal of $ia$ is $-i \frac{1}{a}$

Comment: @JackCrawford Why not $\frac{i^2 b^2}{i a} = \frac{i b^2}{a}$?

Comment: If it works, you definitely need to be careful on how you define the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula works as long as $\Re(a) > 0$.

However, if $a$ is pure imaginary, the integral does not converge to a number, unless $b$ is pure imaginary as well.  And the result is not the same:  If $a$ is pure imaginary then the integral is 
$$
\frac{(1-i)\pi}{\sqrt{2a}}e^{(ib^2-4ac)/(4a)}
$$

And if $\Re(a) < 0$ the integral always diverges.

Comment: Thanks. How did you arrive at that coefficient? Or, what topic do I need to learn to replicate your equation for pure imaginary $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

In the complex case the term inside the integral is always of magnitude 1, so it never converges.

You could make the $b$ and $c$ complex without any problem.